# building an automated timetable scheduling app

Tags: algorithm, logic

I want to build an automated timetable scheduling app. but am finding it difficult to get my logic right. this is what i have do so far.

1. The system is meant for a university but am just considering one faculty  for start.
2. There is an existing list of all courses and their various credit hours. Most of the courses are 3 credit hours and the rest are 2 credit hours. All 3 credit hours course must be divided into two separate period(days) proportionally 2:1.
3. There are 12 hours in a normal class day but each student or class can have at most 6 hours a day and at least an hour a day.
4. Each student from from first year to third offers at least 5 courses and at most 8 courses .
5. Fourth/final year students offer 5 courses.
6. Each course must be taken by a particular year group. therefore given the course a location where it would be taught(classroom).

up until this stage I am mixing ideas and am not getting anything right. Please if any one could help or has a better algorithm to build this in php I would be glad.

Comment: Can you show us the code? Right now there's little to work out from, I'm not even sure what the problem is.

Comment: minor grammar correction